# How to assign a dynamic dataname to an object from an array in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is my array created in JQUERY:

```
var arrayName = ["xyz", "pxz", ["jfs"], "lop"];
```

This is my JQuery Code:

```
$("table tbody#ci_tbl tr").each(function()
  {
    $(this).find('td').not(':first').each (function()
        {
            demoArray = {};
            demoArray.investigationName = $(this).data("name");
            ExampleArray.push(demoArray);
        }); 
  });
```

There's an expression of `demoArray.investigationName` what i want to do is i want to change this `investigationName` by the element that is present in the index location according to the loop it is iterating means

if the loop counter is one it should make `demoArray.xyz`, if the loop counter is two it should make `demoArray.pxz` and so on. I tried but it says expression should be in left how to achieve this kind of thing ?

Comment: Maybe provide the code you have now thats not working? So you are trying to set values of `demoArray` object dynamically (with keys from `arrayName`)?

Comment: Please show expected results and provide a [mcve]. None of this is very clear

Answer (score 0):

it may be a good idea to keep each element of the array line by line. I have made a name for it to be clear here, but you can use it as an array if you need it. So you will be able to access the desired multi-dimensional array

Get data for example

```
var row = 0;
var coloumn = 2;
console.log(arrayData[row][coloumn]);
```

```js
var objectData = [];
var arrayData = [];
$("tr").each(function(){
    var _trDataObject = {};
    var _trDataArray = [];
    $(this).find('td').not(':first').each (function(){
            _trDataObject[$(this).html()] = $(this).html();
            _trDataArray.push($(this).html());
        }); 
        objectData.push(_trDataObject);
        arrayData.push(_trDataArray);
});
console.log(objectData);
console.log(arrayData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>a1</td><td>a2</td><td>a3</td><td>a4</td><td>a5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>b1</td><td>b2</td><td>b3</td><td>b4</td><td>b5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>c1</td><td>c2</td><td>c3</td><td>c4</td><td>c5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```